# Add operationtimeout to channel implemented in code

Tags: c#, wcf

I have seen references on how to cast to a proxy such as:

```
((IContextChannel)client.InnerChannel).OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,240);
```

to set an operationtimeout but I am using client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

How do I cast the channel to IContextChannel?  I hope this makes sense. I don't have a complete grasp on channels in WCF.

Thanks

Alexei,

Not sure how to implement your suggestion.
In this code how would I set an operationtimeout?

```
        try
        {
            Binding multipleTokensBinding = MultiAuthenticationFactorBinding.CreateMultiFactorAuthenticationBinding();
            System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            EndpointAddress endpointaddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://justsomeservice"), EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("someone.com"));

            ChannelFactory<TransActionSvc.TransactionPortType> channelFactory = null;
            TransActionSvc.TransactionPortType client = null;

            channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<TransActionSvc.TransactionPortType>(multipleTokensBinding, endpointaddress);
            BindingElementCollection elements = channelFactory.Endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();
            elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>().IncludeTimestamp = true;

            channelFactory.Endpoint.Binding = new CustomBinding(elements);

            channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.Root, X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "xxx");
            channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.Root, X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "xxx");

            channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = Properties.Settings.Default.UserName;
            channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = Properties.Settings.Default.Password;

            TransActionSvc.fetchTranDataAsAttachmentRequest req = new WF_Prod_Svc.TransActionSvc.fetchTranDataAsAttachmentRequest();
            TransActionSvc.fetchTranDataAsAttachmentResponse res = new WF_Prod_Svc.TransActionSvc.fetchTranDataAsAttachmentResponse();
            TransActionSvc.FetchTranDataAsAttachmentRq_Type reqtype = new WF_Prod_Svc.TransActionSvc.FetchTranDataAsAttachmentRq_Type();
            TransActionSvc.FetchTranDataAsAttachmentRs_Type restype = new WF_Prod_Svc.TransActionSvc.FetchTranDataAsAttachmentRs_Type();
            TransActionSvc.EndpointReferenceType endpntref = new WF_Prod_Svc.TransActionSvc.EndpointReferenceType();

            XmlAttribute actionAttrib1 = doc.CreateAttribute("soapenv", "mustUnderstand", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            actionAttrib1.Value = "0";
            XmlAttribute actionAttrib2 = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns");
            actionAttrib2.Value = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/addressing";
            XmlAttribute[] objAcctionAtrb = new XmlAttribute[2];
            objAcctionAtrb.SetValue(actionAttrib1, 0);
            objAcctionAtrb.SetValue(actionAttrib2, 1);

            TransActionSvc.AttributedURI action = new WF_Prod_Svc.TransActionSvc.AttributedURI();
            action.AnyAttr = objAcctionAtrb;
            action.Value = "Transaction";

            TransActionSvc.AttributedURI messageid = new WF_Prod_Svc.TransActionSvc.AttributedURI();
            messageid.AnyAttr = objAcctionAtrb;
            messageid.Value = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            TransActionSvc.AttributedURI to = new WF_Prod_Svc.TransActionSvc.AttributedURI();
            to.AnyAttr = objAcctionAtrb;
            to.Value = "XGI";

            TransActionSvc.EndpointReferenceType endpointreference = new WF_Prod_Svc.TransActionSvc.EndpointReferenceType();
            TransActionSvc.ReferencePropertiesType referenceproperties = new WF_Prod_Svc.TransActionSvc.ReferencePropertiesType();

            if (Svc_Division.Parsed) { reqtype.division = Svc_Division.StringValue; }
            try{reqtype.startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Svc_StartDate.StringValue);}
            catch (FormatException ex){LogMessageToFile("Invalid Start date. " + ex.Message);}
            try{reqtype.endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Svc_EndDate.StringValue);}
            catch (FormatException ex){LogMessageToFile("Invalid End date. " + ex.Message);}
            if (Svc_DateType.StringValue == "T")
            {
                reqtype.transactionDateType = TransActionSvc.TransactionDateType_Enum.TransactionDate;
            }
            else
            {
                reqtype.transactionDateType = TransActionSvc.TransactionDateType_Enum.PostingDate;
            }
            switch (Svc_TransType.StringValue)
            {
                case "OOP":
                    reqtype.transactionType = TransActionSvc.TransactionType_Enum.OOP;
                    break;
                case "CHARGES":
                    reqtype.transactionType = TransActionSvc.TransactionType_Enum.CHARGES;
                    break;
                default:
                    reqtype.transactionType = TransActionSvc.TransactionType_Enum.ALL;
                    break;
            }

            System.Xml.XmlElement companyid = doc.CreateElement("companyId");
            companyid.InnerText = Properties.Settings.Default.CompanyID;
            System.Xml.XmlElement[] objectarray = new System.Xml.XmlElement[1];
            objectarray.SetValue(companyid, 0);
            referenceproperties.Any = objectarray;
            endpointreference.ReferenceProperties = referenceproperties;

            req.Action = action;
            req.MessageID = messageid;
            req.To = to;
            req.ReplyTo = endpointreference;
            req.fetchTranDataAsAttachment = reqtype;

            try
            {
                client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

                //THIS DOES NOT WORK
                client.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,10,0); 

                res = client.fetchTranDataAsAttachment(req);
                if (res.fetchTranDataAsAttachmentResponse1.WFFaultList != null)
                {
                    LogLine = string.Format("FaultCode({0});FaultType({1});FaultReason({2});Severity({3})",
                                res.fetchTranDataAsAttachmentResponse1.WFFaultList[0].faultCode,
                                res.fetchTranDataAsAttachmentResponse1.WFFaultList[0].faultType,
                                res.fetchTranDataAsAttachmentResponse1.WFFaultList[0].faultReasonText,
                                res.fetchTranDataAsAttachmentResponse1.WFFaultList[0].severity);
                }
                if (res.fetchTranDataAsAttachmentResponse1.attachment != null)
                {
                    string attachFileName = res.fetchTranDataAsAttachmentResponse1.attachment.fileName;
                    byte[] filebytes = res.fetchTranDataAsAttachmentResponse1.attachment.binaryData.Value;
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "..\\..\\" + res.fetchTranDataAsAttachmentResponse1.attachment.fileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
                    fs.Write(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length);
                    fs.Close();
                    DateTime EndReceive = DateTime.Now;
                    TimeSpan elapsed = EndReceive.Subtract(BeginReceive);
                    LogLine = string.Format("Arguments: [{0}]; FileName: {1}; FileSize: {2} bytes; ElapsedTime: {3} seconds", arguments.Trim(), attachFileName, filebytes.Length.ToString(), elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString());
                    LogMessageToFile(LogLine);
                }
            }
            catch (CommunicationException ex1)
            {
                Abort((IChannel)client, channelFactory);
                FaultException fe = null;
                Exception tmp = ex1;
                while (tmp != null)
                {
                    fe = tmp as FaultException;
                    if (fe != null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    tmp = tmp.InnerException;
                }
                if (fe != null)
                {
                    string errmsg = string.Format("The server sent back a fault: {0}", fe.CreateMessageFault().Reason.GetMatchingTranslation().Text);
                    LogMessageToFile(errmsg);
                }
                else
                {
                    string errmsg = string.Format("The request failed with exception: {0}", ex1.Message.ToString());
                    LogMessageToFile(errmsg);
                }
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                Abort((IChannel)client, channelFactory);
                string errmsg = string.Format("The request timed out ");
                DateTime EndReceive = DateTime.Now;
                TimeSpan elapsed = EndReceive.Subtract(BeginReceive);
                LogLine = string.Format("Arguments: [{0}]; Exception: {1}; ElapsedTime: {2} seconds", arguments.Trim(), errmsg, elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString());
                LogMessageToFile(LogLine);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Abort((IChannel)client, channelFactory);
                string errmsg = string.Format("The request failed with unexpected exception: {0}", ex.Message.ToString());
                LogMessageToFile(errmsg);
            }
            finally
            {
                ((IChannel)client).Close();
                channelFactory.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Edited my reply. Please correct title as you aren't casting ChannelFactory to anything...

Comment: Title Changed.  Does that more accurately describe it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will not get any usefuls (non-null/non-exception) result by casting channel factory to channel interface since there is no point for factory to implement any of channel interfaces.

You can cast channel to some other channel interface and likely get useful result if you know what type of channel is used like in the code your refer to.

EDIT: I think `((IContextChannel)channel).OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,10,0);`  should work.

Note: title of your post does not match your code...

Comment: I didn't know about casting to IContextChannel. I was looking for a channel timeout months ago and gave up. Thanks man!